# How can I add a column in the 4th position in a txt file using sed, awk?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I've got a txt file with this content:

```
   name    space   valid   date1        date2 
   abc     mon     yes    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
   def     tue     yes    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
   ghi     wed     yes    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
   jkl     thu     yes    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
```

I need to add a column in the fourth position of the file with a header "location" and content as shown below.

```
   name    space   valid   location     date1        date2 
   abc     mon     yes    newyork    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
   def     tue     yes    newyork    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
   ghi     wed     yes    newyork    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
   jkl     thu     yes    newyork    2022-10-10   2022-10-10
```

Is there any way to do it using one the Linux commands like sed, awk?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==1{$0="name, space, valid, location, date1, date2"} NR>1{$3=sprintf("\t,%s",$3)}1' values.txt
```

Any help would be much appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Is it comma separated or space separated? Why are you using `FS=OFS=","` ?

Comment: Its tab space separated @anubhava

Comment: Does every line start with a tab or other white space as in the example you posted? If not, please [edit] your question to fix the example so it looks like your real data.

Comment: Every column starts with a tab space and also I edited the example, thank you @Ed Morton

Comment: Not a correct dupe link. None of the answers on other question will work for this problem

Comment: So because it's a PIPE rather than a TAB makes the problem different? Give me a break.

Comment: @tink: Take a complete break then replace pipe with tab and test. Then please comment if you get same output as expected by OP here

Comment: @anubhava ... [so] is about reusable answers, not about fixing each individuals question. We're meant to provide general guidance to problem solving as far as I'm concerned. No, it wouldn't create the header, but that's a separate issue. He presented two problems - it should really have been closed w/ needs more focus ...

Comment: `that's a separate issue`: No it is not IMHO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
{$3 = $3 OFS (NR == 1 ? "location" : "newyork")} 1' file

name  space  valid  location  date1       date2
abc   mon    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
def   tue    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
ghi   wed    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
jkl   thu    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
```

PS: If all of your lines start with a tab space then use `$4` instead of `$3` in above command since first column will be empty.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
{$4 = $4 OFS (NR == 1 ? "location" : "newyork")} 1' file

   name  space  valid  location  date1       date2
   abc   mon    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
   def   tue    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
   ghi   wed    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
   jkl   thu    yes    newyork   2022-10-10  2022-10-10
```